# How to get the most dependent packages from npm registery?

Tags: node.js, rest, npm

I am writing an api to fetch the top 100 npm registery packages and record the historical data of their movement on every day .

one way to accomplish this task is to parse '[the most depended-upon packages](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended)' page from npmjs.com.

Is there any rest api to consume and fetch this info particularly?